# Convert in command line an sfd file (fontforge) to ttf, otf, woff, svg

Tags: command-line, fonts, conversion

I search a way to automatically convert an sfd file (The work format of Fontforge) to the main font format (at least otf, ttf, woof, svg).

But I need to do it in command line, I don’t need to do it from GUI.

Unfortunately it seams that the Fontforge application don’t support it (I read the manpage and there is no mention of this usage). Anyway, I need to do it from command line but it’s not necessary to do it from Fontforge. Any other application who can convert the Fontforge work format “SFD” to the main font format.

So, how can I get a commands like this:

```
sfd2ttf input.sfd output.ttf
sfd2otf input.sfd output.otf
sfd2woff input.sfd output.woff
sfd2svg input.sfd output.svg
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with Fontforge, see [here](https://fontforge.github.io/cliargs.html):

> -c script-string
>
> If FontForge's first (or second, if the first is -lang) argument is "-c" then the argument that follows will be treated as a string containing scripting commands, and those commands will be executed. All remaining arguments will be passed to the script.
>
> ```
> $ fontforge -c 'Open($1); Generate($2)' foo.sfd foo.ttf
> ```
>
> Will read a font from "foo.sfd" and then generate a truetype font from it called "foo.ttf"

In your case you can create a script, say `convertsfd`, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); Generate($2)' "$1" "$2"
```

make it executable, and call it like this:

```
$ ./convertsfd foo.sfd foo.ttf
```

Change the second argument to `foo.otf` or to other formats as needed, I only tested with `ttf` and `otf`.

To call the script from anywhere, just place it in your `~/.local/bin`, or some other directory in your `PATH`.

Comment: The produced ttf misses metadata from the input sfd like copyright, weight, version. Those are filled when doing the conversion in the GUI. How do I keep these fields when converting via the command line?